# Discord.js bot not logging in

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a discord bot and i have no idea what's wrong with my code i mean look:

```
 const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES"
    ]
});

client.login('you thought haha')
```

I tried various tutorials but it's still not working

Comment: Do you get any errors? How are you starting the node process?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking like about the intents and there's simple mistake as i've seen. If you wan't to open all intents i recommend you this;

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: new Discord.Intents(32767)
});
```

If you wan't specific intents then you should make them like;

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
})
```

**Also don't forget to open your intents from bot section on your developer panel!**

More info [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#intents) on docs.

Comment: Just small FYI, intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071.

Comment: What are new intents?

Comment: Intents are listed [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#gateway-intents). But someone actually made [this](https://ziad87.net/intents/) to help calculate it to a bitfield just check all the boxes and look at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have already installed  Node.js and discord.js, and also have a bot setup.

If you check [discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-configuration-files), they provide you the following code to start your bot:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

Then, open your terminal and run `node index.js` (assuming that your file name is index.js) to start the process. If you see "Ready!" after a few seconds, you're good to go!

I strongly recommend for you to follow [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin), it helped me a lot with the first steps with the discord bot.

Also, make sure that you have the right scopes selected for your bot: [image: Bot scopes]

Answer (score -1):

I think the error is on the client declaration. You have to capıtalize the first letter of "intents". So the code becomes:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({
    Intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES"
    ]
});
client.login("your token here");
```

And also please make sure that on your discord developers page you have your intents turned on.

Comment: No, Intents should be called from `discord.js`. So you can make it `Discord.Intents` not just Intents.